# how do i pause the recording screen in python

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am creating a screen recording software in python.

And its almost completed in this the screen_capturing() function grabs the screenshot and store it inside an array and then opencv convert these images into a video file.

So i have the start and stop function but now i want to pause these while running and then able to resume it again.

How can i achieve that pause/resume part

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageGrab
import cv2
import numpy as np
import threading

p = ImageGrab.grab()
a, b = p.size
filename=(f'C://Users/{os.getlogin()}/desktop/temp_vid.mp4')
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'X264')
frame_rate = 10
out = cv2.VideoWriter() 

def screen_capturing():

    global capturing
    capturing = True

    while capturing:

        img = ImageGrab.grab()
        frame = np.array(img)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        out.write(frame)

def start_screen_capturing():

    if not out.isOpened():

        out.open(filename,fourcc, frame_rate,(a,b))
    print(' rec started')
    t1=threading.Thread(target=screen_capturing, daemon=True)
    t1.start()

def stop_screen_capturing():
    global capturing
    capturing = False
    out.release()
    print('complete')

start_cap = Button(root, text='Start Recording', width=30, command=start_screen_capturing)
start_cap.grid(row=0, column=0)
stop_cap = Button(root, text='Stop Recording', width=30, command=stop_screen_capturing)
stop_cap.grid(row=0, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can stop taking screenshots for that moment and then resume it later on. Just you need to concatenate the previous recordings with new ones for that you can use global variables also.

Comment: @AmitRautray can you show me how can i do it with the code in the answer section. it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yeah sure. @jadu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these functions for pause and resume with Buttons.

```
def pause_screen_capturing():
    global capturing
    capturing = False
    print("Paused")

def resume_screen_capturing():
    global capturing
    capturing = True
    if not out.isOpened():
        out.open(filename,fourcc, frame_rate,(a,b))
    t1=threading.Thread(target=screen_capturing, daemon=True)
    t1.start()
    print("Resumed")
```